# How to extract txt files from multple folders and merging all into a single folder?

Tags: files, scripting, python3, text, merge

I have 100 of folder where in each folder I have another folder with same name and inside that folder there is a .txt file which I want to extract and merge all the txt files into a new folder.

Please help me with a script in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the root folder of 100 sub folders and find all of the .txt files, copy them into the new folder `~/tests`:

`find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp "{}" ~/tests/ \;`

Comment: thanks it worked...now if i want to convert all these txt files into csv format ....can I do that?

Comment: sure, but have to see the contents of txt files. Please create one new question.